# Finding information from multiple columns for a specific value

Tags: r

This question is related to my previous one. I need to know how many males (m) and females (f) are unmarried or single.

So I think I found the right function but the answer but I'm not 100% sure. I mainly asked this question to just to see if I'm on the right path. This is the function I used. I replaced the actual numbers with the pound symbol so there wasn't an error. I'm assuming 'Y' means TRUE in this case and 'N' is obviously False

```
table(example.test$Sex, example.test$Married == 'Y')
   
    FALSE TRUE
  F   ##   ##
  M   ### ###

**Previous Question**

     Income   Career   Age   Sex Married
1.   39540    Lawyer   20    F    N
2.   45098    Teacher  65    F    y
3.   54565    Doctor   45    M    y
4.   48356    Teacher  26    M    N
5.   68959    Nurse    32    F   y
```

I'll call this example.test

Comment: Welcome, @ellen, to SO! Each question you post is independent, so whereas I'd like to help I am unfamiliar with your previous question. In short: we need you to post some date so we can advise whether your function works or if not why

Comment: Sorry about that! Updated it so it would make more sense

Comment: `table(example.test[c("Sex","Married")])` should give you what you want

Comment: `with(example.test, table(Sex, Married))` is another way to do it

Comment: you could also do `table(example.test$Sex, example.test$Married)`

Comment: I appreciate the help from the both of you! Onyambu your first suggestion worked!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
example.test <- dplyr::data_frame('Income'=c(39540, 45098, 54565, 48356, 68959), 'Career'=c('Lawyer', 'Teacher', 'Doctor', 'Teacher', 'Nurse'), 'Age'=c(20, 65, 45, 26, 32), 'Sex'=c('F', 'F', 'M', 'M', 'F'), 'Married'=c('N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N', 'Y'))

example.test %>% 
  count(Sex, Married, name= "Count")
```

**The Table:**
[image: The Table:]

Comment: I tried both and I'm getting errors. ! Must group by variables found in `.data`.

Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I'm just trying to find the amount of unmarried men, unmarried women, married men and married woman.  So it would be 4 different values

Comment: The code I posted does that, @ellen: it produces a short table (the one I've just added to my above answer). 1 singe F, 2 married F, 1 married M, and 1 single M. Might the problem be that I used 'example.test' as df name, whereas your comment indicates you're using `.data` instead?